# How can i place my chart in the middle of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to place my chart in the middle of the page however I am finding it difficult for some reason.

Also how can I make the tooltip hover over blue bar as right now it is being presented in the corner of the page.

Could some one help me to place me chart in the middle and allow the tooltip is hover over the blue bars in the chart.

Thank you!

This is my css:

```
.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

#title {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold; 
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    pointer-events: none;
}
#tooltip.hidden {
    display: none;
}
#tooltip p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

This is my d3.js:

```
<script>
var margins = {
    top: 12,
    left: 150,
    right: 24,
    bottom: 24
},
legendPanel = {
    width: 0
},
width = 800 - margins.left - margins.right - legendPanel.width,
    height = 300 - margins.top - margins.bottom,
    dataset = [{
        data: [{
            month: 'Jan Sales',
            count: 35 
        }, {
            month: 'XMAS',
            count:5
        }
         ]
    }

    ],
    series = dataset.map(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    }),
    dataset = dataset.map(function (d) {
        return d.data.map(function (o, i) {
            // Structure it so that your numeric
            // axis (the stacked amount) is y
            return {
                y: o.count,
                x: o.month
            };
        });
    }),
    stack = d3.layout.stack();

stack(dataset);

var dataset = dataset.map(function (group) {
    return group.map(function (d) {
        // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0
        return {
            x: d.y,
            y: d.x,
            x0: d.y0
        };
    });
}),
    svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width', width + margins.left + margins.right + legendPanel.width)
        .attr('height', height + margins.top + margins.bottom)
        .append('g')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margins.left + ',' + margins.top + ')'),
    xMax = d3.max(dataset, function (group) {
        return d3.max(group, function (d) {
            return d.x + d.x0;
        });
    }),
    xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, xMax])
        .range([0, width]),
    months = dataset[0].map(function (d) {
        return d.y;
    }),
    _ = console.log(months),
    yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(months)
        .rangeRoundBands([0, height], .5),
    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom'),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient('left'),
    colours = d3.scale.category10(),
    groups = svg.selectAll('g')
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .style('fill', function (d, i) {
        return colours(i);
    }),
    rects = groups.selectAll('rect')
        .data(function (d) {
        return d;
    })
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x0);
    })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
        return yScale(d.y);
    })
        .attr('height', function (d) {
        return yScale.rangeBand();
    })
        .attr('width', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.x);
    })
        .on('mouseover', function (d) {
        var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x')) / 2 + width / 2;
        var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + yScale.rangeBand() / 2;

        d3.select('#tooltip')
            .style('left', xPos + 'px')
            .style('top', yPos + 'px')
            .select('#value')
            .text(d.x);

        d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', false);
    })
        .on('mouseout', function () {
        d3.select('#tooltip').classed('hidden', true);
    })

    svg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append('rect')
    .attr('fill', 'yellow')
    .attr('width', 160)
    .attr('height', 30 * dataset.length)
    .attr('x', width + margins.left)
    .attr('y', 0);

series.forEach(function (s, i) {
    svg.append('text')
        .attr('fill', 'black')
        .attr('x', width + margins.left + 8)
        .attr('y', i * 24 + 24)
        .text(s);
    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('fill', colours(i))
        .attr('width', 60)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr('x', width + margins.left + 90)
        .attr('y', i * 24 + 6);
});

</script>
```

And this is my html for the tooltip:

```
<div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
    <p>
       <span id="value">100</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define *"in the middle of the page"*. Also, why do you have a `jQuery` and a `nvd3` tag?

Comment: like in the center of the web page and i am using some elements of jquery in my page. i hope it make sense when i said that i want my chart in the middle of the page

Comment: The fact that you're using jQuery does not mean you should tag this question with jQuery. Using that reasoning, every D3 question should have the HTML tag. Regarding the center, do you mean vertically? Horizontally? Both?

Comment: ah right thanks for clarifying that, and i mean both so the chart sits in the middle of the page.

Comment: Ok, so let me explain the situation: this has nothing to do with D3. In your code you're simply selecting the `<body>` and appending the SVG. I suggest you posting another question, with the HTML, CSS and Javascript tags, asking how: 1. get the window height, 2.get the window width, 3.creating a div with the SVG inside in such a way that the margins will be the same to top, bottom, left and right margins of the window.

Answer (score 1):

to place a block in the middle of a page you can use a very simple css setting. As you want the chart to be in the middle add the following to your css

```
    #tooltip {
      margin: 0 auto
    }
```

to add a hover function to a class or id you could use the following css. Just change the values to your corresponding id or class

```
#example:hover {
background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. could you put this in a JS fiddle for me please if you dont mind.

Comment: @dave Why don't you make a JS fiddle of the code in your question, then people looking to answer can fix it and post the new link back. You'll find you get far more answers that way.